# VBA add columns if cell contains value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working with the following, but having difficulty with selecting the actual cell is on during the loop.  It's pulling a range of cells, checking if their value > 0 and then if so, should add 3 columns to it's right. This is what I have so far, not sure how efficient it is:

```
    Dim varray As Variant
    Dim x As Long

    varray = Range("E13:AK13").Value

    For x = UBound(varray, 1) To LBound(varray, 1) Step -1
        If varray(x, 1) > 0 Then

            varray(x, 1).Activate 'ISSUE ON THIS LINE
            ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert (xlShiftToRight)
            ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert (xlShiftToRight)
            ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert (xlShiftToRight)
            'substract 2
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this instead.

```
Dim x As Long, rng As Range

Set rng = Range("E13:AK13")

For Each cell In rng
    If cell > 0 Then
        cell.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert (xlShiftToRight)
        cell.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert (xlShiftToRight)
        cell.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert (xlShiftToRight)
    End If
Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using array it would be very difficult to select the intended cell. I have done some modification to the code, check if it works for you.

```
Dim varray As Range
Dim x As Long

Set varray = Range("E13:AK13") 

''For x = UBound(varray, 1) To LBound(varray, 1) Step -1
For Each c In varray
    If c.Value > 0 Then

        c.Select 'ISSUE ON THIS LINE
        ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert (xlShiftToRight)
        ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert (xlShiftToRight)
        ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert (xlShiftToRight)
        'substract 2
    End If
Next c
```